# Elegant way to format numbers right aligned in a HTML table

Tags: html, css

Is there a  elegant way to format numbers right aligned in a HTML table?

**For Example:**

This:

> 0/0 Hz
>
> 10/600 Hz
>
> 1200/1200 HZ

Should be like this:

```
   0 /    0 Hz

  10 /  600 Hz

1200 / 1200 HZ
```

My table looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/cwwxrL8a/

Comment: yes: put these numbers and slashes into seperate table cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elegant is a very, very subjective in this case...

It depends if you'd rather mess up the content inside your table cells or mess up your table. It depends how this table is being populated.

I personally prefer to not make a table with tons of cells, and I definitely don't like the idea of having a column that's just full of `/`s.

I would wrap spans around your two data parts, the over and the total. The downfall for this one is the width setting is necessary. But the upside is it doesn't use table for styling.

A fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/9183ao41/2/

Choose your poison.

Comment: Woow, great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is this approx what you mean?

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Freq</th>
    <td></td>
    <th>description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>RS64</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td>1200 Hz</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SE1225<br></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1200 Hz</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SE1226</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1200 Hz</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, if you want to move them right just give it position: relative or absolute and set right: 0; OR float: right;

Comment: No, The numbers are just centered. I want to bi aligned right and the '/' has to be in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that what you want to do is possible with giving ids/classes to each part of the text inside that table. Or as @Johannes said, putting everything in it's own cell.

One thing I can recommend is playing around with `padding`, `word-spacing` and `letter-spacing` to see if you can find a look that fits what you want:

```
.freq{
  text-align: right;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```